# How big is a sonar database?

Tags: database, size, evaluation, diskspace, sonarqube

It might looks like a dumb question. In fact it's more like a poll: how big is your Sonar database? I need this to estimate the requirements for a virtual machine to host my Sonar instance.

Also:

- how big is your team?
- how many additional bytes is used in the Sonar database for every new commit?

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: maybe not a dumb question but it seems to belong elsewhere.

Comment: Where do you think this question belongs (another tag, another site?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're referring to [Sonar from Codehaus](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Documentation), and not [SOund Navigation And Ranging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonar).

From the [installation page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Install+Sonar):

> The Sonar web server requires 500Mo of RAM to run efficiently.
>
> In terms of data space and as an indication, on Nemo the public instance of Sonar, 2Go of data space are used to analyze more than 6 million LOC with an history of 2 years. For every 1'000 LOC to analyze the database stores 350 Ko of data space.

Comment: Gilbert: these calculations don't add up in our case -- we have run out of 1G table space for a project that is less than 500K lines. Any ideas/pointers of what to do?

Comment: @Sasha O:  I'm not a Sonar expert, but you could try the House Cleaning & Performances sections described in the documentation http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/

Comment: Sounds like you are comparing apples and digerdoos. OP is asking about the database and these are stats for the web server.