# SonarQube database - Requirements (Sizing, activity, IOPS)

Tags: sonarqube

Please, have you got any statistics about the database utilization for SonarQube?
*For example : Sizing, numbers of IOPS etc...*

I already check this documentations :

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements

[How big is a sonar database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607864/how-big-is-a-sonar-database)

In fact, my DBA asked me several informations before to create my database. DBA need to know the activity, sizing (disk space), numbers of IOPS (average) etc... (maximum of information)

Please, could you give me more informations about that?
For example, with 100 differents projets, around 100 000 lines of code in each project. In average, what will be the size and activity (iops etc...) in the database?

Thx in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

What is your DB? You won't get the same numbers for Oracle and MySql.