# Sonarqube - Very big database

Tags: database, sonarqube, storage

I've found this post about the usual size of a Sonarqube Database:

[How big is a sonar database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607864/how-big-is-a-sonar-database)

In our case, we have 3,584,947 LOC to analyze. If every 1,000 LOC stores 350 Ko of data space it should use about 1.2Gb But we've found that our SonarQube database actually stores more than 20Gb...

The official documentation (https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements) says that for 30 millions LOC with 4 years of history, they use less than 20Gb...

In our General Settings > Database Cleaner we have all default value except for "Delete all analyses after" which is set to 360 instead of 260

What can create so much data in our case?

We use sonarqube 6.7.1 version

**EDIT**

As @simonbrandhof asked, here are our biggest tables

```
| Table Name             | # Records  | Data (KB)  |
|`dbo.project_measures`  | 12'334'168 |  6'038'384 | 
|`dbo.ce_scanner_context`|    116'401 | 12'258'560 |
|`dbo.issues`            |  2'175'244 |  2'168'496 |
```

Comment: i also expirienced that, for us the biggest table is live_measures, which i assume is connected to the live update of quality gates.

Comment: additionlly i recommend to ask this in the mailinglist: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube

Comment: @SimonSchrottner FYI the table live_measures has been introduced in 7.0. Anyway it should not change the total size because it contains data that have been extracted from another table.

Answer (score 2):

20Gb of disk sounds way too big for 3.5M lines of code. For comparison the internal PostgreSQL schema at SonarSource is 2.1Gb for 1M lines of code.

I recommend to clean-up db in order to refresh statistics and reclaim dead storage. Command is `VACUUM FULL` on PostgreSQL. There are probably similar command on other databases. If it's not better then please provide the list of biggest tables.

EDIT

The unexpected size of table `ce_scanner_context` is due to https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-10658. This bug is going to be fixed in 6.7.4 and 7.2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We are on a SQLServer and our DBA's are looking for the VACCUM FULL equivalent

Comment: I listed the biggest table that we have in the EDIT of my post

Comment: How large was the ES hard drive space used up for 1 million lines?